# What determines the voltage rating of a cable, and why do some cables have \$U_0 = U\$ while others have \$U_0 < U\$?

Tags: voltage, cables, wire, insulation, ratings

Just as an example, let's consider two cables, with voltage ratings being respectively 300/300 V and 300/500 V.

My understanding is that voltage rating is an indication of the quality of the insulation, and it is expressed with \$U_0/U\$ where:

- \$U_0\$ is the maximum voltage the wire can support between phase and earth (or any adjacent non-insulated conductor) before it starts conducting
- \$U\$ is the maximum voltage supported between two phases

Assuming that's correct, I am still baffled as to what the determines the difference between \$U_0\$ and \$U\$ (when they differ) and most importantly, why sometimes they're equal ?

I did a lot of research online (probably the wrong way) but I couldn't find an explanation nor a practical example which would give me the intuition on how and why this numbers could make sense.

I am adding an image to explain my current understanding which I think should demonstrate why I think \$U\$ should always be greater than \$U_0\$ since there would always be more insulation between two phases.
Note that in the image *Earth* (the blue rectangle) is just an adjacent non-insulated conductor.

[image: voltage rating current understanding]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140286/discussion-on-question-by-denny-baldini-what-determines-the-voltage-rating-of-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Added**:  *Some* of the confusion can be elminated by the definition listed [here](https://tratosgroup.com/tratos-cable-academy/what-is-voltage-rating/).

- U being the r.m.s value between any two phase conductors of a multicore cable **or of a system of single core cables**.

This probably makes sense of most of the examples. The higher rating is probably one that would need a per-application assessment.

In the case of eg [this](https://www.comcavi.it/cavi/cavi-elettrici-cpr/fs17/) 450/750 V single core cable that you gave as an example I'd interpret the ratings as

- 400V from conductor to an adjacent ground in contact with the cable sheath.
- 750V between the conductors of two such cables in physical contact but not in contact with a grounded surface or conductor.

The 750V rating could apply in eg a non conductive conduit with two or more such cables carrying separate phases, with the conduit rated at say 1 kV.  In such a case contact with the outer of any of the cables would be subject to the 400V rating.

---

I'm making this an answer because it summarises what is said in the many excellent comments. Read the comments for more details.

The reasons vary.
It may not be obvious in every case, but in some instances looking at application, use of conductors (internal earth wire or not, and other factors) may give some clues.

In some cases it may in fact not have a good formal basis. The manufacturer is held to there speification by regulatory requirements and may find it easier or more cost effective or ... to meet requirements one way or the other.

In some cases the manufacturer may provide a \$U_0 = U\$ multicore cable because the sheath is intended from mechanical protection and they do not provide any assurances of it's electrical capabilities.

In some cases having an internal earth wire may lead to a \$U_0 = U\$ rating and a lack of one allows \$U_0 < U\$.

It is unlikely that a \$U_0 > U\$ cable exists.
(This **might** occur with eg symmetrial 3 phase packing around an earth wire and a filler in the interstitial space so that the phas-earth insulation paths are electrically shorter than phase-phase paths).

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I was hoping to find a more strict and formal definition while it all seems a bit loose, dependant on the cable of interest, and regulations.

If what you're saying is true means \$U_0\$ could refer to *earth wire* inside the sheath or to any conductor outside depending on the cable of reference.

Does that mean in [FS17 450/750 V](https://www.comcavi.it/cavi/cavi-elettrici-cpr/fs17/) \$U_0\$ is to be read with respect to an imaginary non-isolated conductor outside the sheath, while \$U\$ with respect to an imaginary adjacent cable of the same kind ?

Comment: @dennybaldini  My answer is proably not the one you were looking for :-( . --> My "answer" was an attempt to summarise the comments and suggest some order. Probably I should make it clearer that while I am an olde and experienced EE my response is my understanding and what others are saying here. Odds are you know more than I do on the matter at this point as you have looked at more related material. || For a more formal answer you may =need to approach a regulatory authority or search regulatory .literatute

Comment: @dennybaldini My addition makes more sense of the ratings

Comment: Your latest addition makes it even clearer thanks, and I accepted your answer as it is a good enough explanation for me right now. 
But I don't exclude getting in touch with some manufacturer/regulatory authority at some point ;)

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hey I found [this one](https://www.keystone-cable.com/resources/ck/files/products/LV/PDF/PP%20Flexible%20Cable.pdf), and I am curious to know how would you interpret the voltage rating here.

We have a 3-Core: (Green/Yellow, Blue & Brown) with a voltage rating of 250/440V.
The way I would interpret it here is that \$U = 440\$ would apply between any of three cores (even though one of them is earth), while \$U_0 = 250\$ would apply to an imaginary adjacent conductor outside the sheath.

Comment: @dennybaldini  If I HAD to interpret that ( :-) ) I'd say they were rating the outer sheath as low or no insulation and then applying "between any two phase conductors" to brown and blue = phase and neutral. ie wire to wire is 440V and  ay one wire's insulation to something against its outer surface or against the sheath is 250 V. || Most users would probably immediately understand this as saying it was suiutable for 3 phase A use with 230V per phase to ground. (Which is how I would have read it intuitively).